# LUA, modulo and "number has no integer representation"

Tags: lua, integer, modulo

I'm newbie in LUA. I want to simple display some time vaule

```
string_buf = string.format ( "%dh %dmin" ,Mode[2]/60,Mode[2]%60 )
```

But my device still inform me that at this line "#2 number has no integer representation". I find info that problem is that modulo give float. So I try to change it for

```
a= math.floor(Mode[2]%60)
string_buf = string.format ( "%dh %dmin" ,Mode[2]/60,a )
```

Result are the same. If I try to display this value as print in console then I see nice integer value- no matter If I made floor or not. Device and simulation in fact not work when rest from divide is not equal to 0

Answer (score 2):

Modulo result is always an integer. Your problem is `Mode[2]/60`.

You cannot use `%d` for a float value. For floats use `%f`.

So either convert `Mode[2]/60` to an integer

```
string_buf = string.format ( "%dh %dmin" ,math.floor(Mode[2]/60+.5), Mode[2]%60 )
```

or using floor division `//` if you don't want to round

```
string_buf = string.format ( "%dh %dmin" ,Mode[2]//60+.5, Mode[2]%60 )
```

or use a float with 0 digits

```
string_buf = string.format ( "%.0fh %dmin" ,Mode[2]/60,Mode[2]%60 )
```

Comment: 1. Modulo result is not always an integer: `1.5 % 1 == 0.5` (if both operands are integers, the result is an integer too however). 2. `%d` works for floats and will simply silently truncate the fractional part in older Lua versions (5.1); using `%f` IMO is bad advice since Lua numbers are doubles, not floats; `%f` adds ugly trailing zeroes & doesn't have enough precision for doubles. I'd recommend `%g` instead.

Comment: Thank's, in fact it's divide not modulo matter.  Works each tip who u write. I will remember about modulo from number with points.